# Cant get array data on mysql with nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var mysql = require('mysql');
app.listen(3000)
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile)
app.get('/product',showConnect)
var mysql_conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'x.x.x.x',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'db'
});
```

When I run with this, it get correct value

```
mysql_conn.query('SELECT query_text FROM catalogsearch_query WHERE `query_text` LIKE "%drawing eye%" ORDER BY  `popularity` DESC LIMIT 0 , 10', function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    for (id in rows) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(rows[id]));
    }
});
```

value on console.log

```
{"query_text":"Etude House Drawing Eye Brow (New)"}
{"query_text":"Etude House Drawing Eye Brow (New) 1 Dark Brown"}
{"query_text":"Etude House Drawing Eye Brow New 4"}
{"query_text":"Etude House Drawing Eye Brow"}
{"query_text":"Etude drawing eye brow"}
{"query_text":"etude drawing eye brow Etude House"}
{"query_text":"drawing eye"}
{"query_text":"drawing eye brow"}
{"query_text":"Etude drawing eye"}
{"query_text":"etude house drawing eye brow duo"}
```

but when I render to page with this code

```
function showConnect(req, res){
    mysql_conn.query('SELECT query_text FROM catalogsearch_query WHERE `query_text` LIKE "%drawing eye%" ORDER BY  `popularity` DESC LIMIT 0 , 10', function(error, rows){
    res.render('product.html', {users: rows})
    })
}
```

on product.html

```
<%
for (var i of coffee){
    %>
        <%= i %>
    <%
}
%>
```

it show this data

```
[object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]
```

I try to run with JSON.stringify() but it show like this

```
[ { " q u e r y _ t e x t " : " E t u d e H o u s e D r a w i n g E y e B r o w ( N e w ) " } , { " q u e r y _ t e x t " : " E t u d e H o u s e D r a w i n g E y e B r o w ( N e w ) 1 D a r k B r o w n " } , { " q u e r y _ t e x t " : " E t u d e H o u s e D r a w i n g E y e B r o w N e w 4 " } , { " q u e r y _ t e x t " : " E t u d e H o u s e D r a w i n g E y e B r o w " } , { " q u e r y _ t e x t " : " E t u d e d r a w i n g e y e b r o w " } , { " q u e r y _ t e x t " : " e t u d e d r a w i n g e y e b r o w E t u d e H o u s e " } , { " q u e r y _ t e x t " : " d r a w i n g e y e " } , { " q u e r y _ t e x t " : " d r a w i n g e y e b r o w " } , { " q u e r y _ t e x t " : " E t u d e d r a w i n g e y e " } , { " q u e r y _ t e x t " : " e t u d e h o u s e d r a w i n g e y e b r o w d u o " } ]
```

My question is 'How can I get data without space? Also need only value without rows name?

Comment: Could you write the output of the mysql query with console.log ?

Comment: Don't you mean to render `<%= i.query_text %>`?

Comment: @maxgallo I have updated output on above

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @funcoding Its error when i change to JSON.parse()

`Exception occured
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: My bad! Can you share the code in product.html?

Comment: Do `res.render('product.html', {users: rows.map(row => row.query_text)})`, and also make sure your product.html is using utf-8 encoding (saved as such, and with `<meta charset="utf-8" />`)

Comment: @funcoding please see product.html code above